# How do I retrieve configured policies for a certain environment?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm trying to find out if the WorkflowPolicySet policy is configured from the Sitecore XP side of things. There seems to be an API to retrieve PolicySets:

```
 {{OpsApiHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/PolicySets
```

However, the /PolicySets request that should return all policy sets never returns anything. You can also request a policy set by name:

```
{{OpsApiHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/PolicySets('WorkflowPolicySet')
```

Which works, but only if you pass the Ops environment. This doesn't work from Sitecore XP, because you always work with Authoring or Shops in that context.

How is this suppose to work? Is there any other way to find out what policies are configured for a certain environment?

Comment: did you try with environment.Policies? environment variable is based on class CommerceEnvironment

Comment: @VladIobagiu I'm trying to do this using the service proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Postman:

```
{{OpsApiHost}}/{{OpsApi}}/Environments('{{Environment}}')?$expand=Components
```

You'll find this request under SitecoreCommerce_DevOps/Environment Management

Comment: Thanks, I know about this postman call. Is there a way to use this from my sitecore code? Using the service proxy?

Answer (score 2):

According to Sitecore support, there is no way to do this with the service proxy and you will have to call the above API yourself (Using HttpClient or any other http library)